# calcLinePoints() method is giving wrong set of points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Steps to reproduce**

1) Draw a line on canvas

2) rotate/drag/modify the line on canvas

3) now try to get the values of x1. y1, x2, y2 using the method and adding top and left to points

**Expected Behavior**

It should give me the updated x1, y1, x2, y2.

**Actual Behavior**

But the values are wrong and line is drawn at some other location using obtained points.

So,i am in need of same feature as it is provided for polygons to get updated points using the following code :

```
  <!--fabric js function to get coordinates of active object-->
    var translatedPoints = polygon.get("points").map(function(p){
    return new fabric.Point(p.x - polygon.minX -polygon.width/2, p.y - polygon.minY - polygon.height/2);
    }).map(function(p){
       return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
    });
```

So my question is , is it possible to do same kind of thing for Line Object?
Here is my JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sL2np4wj/25/
I am printing the new set of points after object modified and drawing line with new obtained points but the obtained points are wrong since line is drawn at some other place

Comment: any runnable code snippet or jsfiddle will be helpful.

Comment: @AminurRashid here is my JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/sL2np4wj/25/    Its giving me wrong set of Points..